# php captcha.org doesn't work

Tags: php, captcha

I have a form with the phpcaptcha.org. But when I submit the form I see a white screen, the captcha script doesn't work, the other code works.
Can someone help me what is wrong with captcha?

thanks in advance.

my submit code is:

```
<?php
session_start();

//captcha
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'securimage/securimage.php';
$securimage = new Securimage();


include 'connect.php';


$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password)VALUES (?, ?)";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);


 $username = $_POST['username'];

 $password = md5($_POST['password']);

$stmt->execute();


//captcha
if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) {
  // the code was incorrect
  // you should handle the error so that the form processor doesn't continue

  // or you can use the following code if there is no validation or you do not know how
  echo "The security code entered was incorrect.<br /><br />";
  echo "Please go <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>back</a> and try again.";
  exit;
}

if (! $sql) {
    echo "Account not created";
} 
    echo 'Account created, click <a href="index.php">here</a>';

$stmt->close();
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

And post the errors.

Comment: The errors are: Warning: include_once(C:/xampp/htdocssecurimage/securimage.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\register.php on line 12

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'C:/xampp/htdocssecurimage/securimage.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\register.php on line 12

Fatal error: Class 'Securimage' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\register.php on line 13

Comment: Read the error message, then read line 5. You're missing the directory seperator. Change line 5 to `include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/securimage/securimage.php'`

Answer (score 2):

I think **the main problem** is hidden in the `include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'securimage/securimage.php';` line. Have you tried putting **another slash (/) before securimage/securimage.php** ? It looks like PHP is trying to include the indicated file, cannot find it due to the lacking slash, continue with the rest of the code, and cannot create a new Securimage variable since the **type is undefined**. if you change `include_once()` to `require_once()`, you will probably get an error.

On the other hand, I would strongly recommend using a stronger hashing algorithm than **MD5**, which is very **weak in terms of security**. Please consider using the built in **[crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)** function of PHP with a better algorithm like **BLOWFISH** or **SHA-512**. If you have PHP 5.5 over above available, you may also find another built-in PHP function called **[password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)** very useful. Hope this has been helpful.